# Google Script comparing two spreadsheet cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need some help for comparing 2 cells content with Google Script. 
Basically I have email addresses in two columns of different spreadsheets and my script must act in different way if the addresses are equal or not. 
When I launch an "if" cycle comparing the two cells the script never recognize that they are the same..
I've tried with if(test=test1) and with if(test==test1) but it doesn't work. What should it be? Thanks!

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {     
   if (values[i][1].length > 0) {
      var test = valuesDB[1][2];
      var test1 = values[i][1];
      if (test==test1) {                       
         var Date = values[i][4];
         var Days = values[i][5];
         var comments = values[i][6]; }
```

Comment: I'd use triple equal signs for comparison.  `if (test===test1) {` Also, add `Logger.log('test: ' + test);` statement to check your values.  In the menu, VIEW the LOGS to see the print out of the Logger.log() statement.

Comment: thanks! it worked. Quick question: if I want to return the var Date outside the if cycle have I to put "return Date;" before the } ?

Comment: `return` just needs to be inside of the function.  [Documentation Mozilla - Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Answer (score 0):

Use triple equal signs for comparison.

```
if (test===test1) {
```

Also, add `Logger.log('test: ' + test);` statement to check your values. In the menu, VIEW the LOGS to see the print out of the Logger.log() statement.